# slider changin value move the slider handler not the container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

In my function, by resizing the container, i am calling a custom trigger function, it works and it moves my handle bar correctly, but the container margin not triggers, it stay as default.

what the issue with my code..? any one help me to sort this.

my code:

```
var stepScrollBar = $(stepRange).slider({
            step:1, //100 is available movement measure
            slide:function(i,ui){
                boardHolder.css({
                    left:-ui.value * (moveSize / 100)
                });     
            },
            change:function(i,ui){
                boardHolder.css({
                    marginLeft:-ui * (moveSize / 100)
                }); 
            }

        });
        $(stepRange).slider('option','value',65); 
           //value sets in handler but not container being unchanged!
        $(stepRange).slider('option','change').call();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed my issue:

```
$(stepRange).slider('value',getPoint(pointOfLeft));
$(stepRange).on('slidechange', function(event,ui){
    boardHolder.css({
        left:-ui.value * (moveSize / 100)
        }); 
});
```